# How to get all rows of an SQL table with left outer join and junction table and insert value on some condition?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a shoes shop website and I am facing issue with SQL. I'm a newbie.

I got 3 tables, products, categories and a junction table many-to-many:

```
table 'categories           table 'products'         junction 'product_category'

-------------------         ---------------------     ------------------------
category_id | title          id | marque | modele      product_id | category_id
1             automne         1   nike     air              1           2
2             hiver           2   adidas   sun              1           7
3             printemps      
4             été
7             top
```

When I click for edit a product, I get a form with all the field I can edit. I got checkboxes inputs for all the categories a product got (ex: product "nike" got 2 categories : top, automne, then it has got 2 inputs named top and automne and they are checked). Now I am trying with the same SQL request, to get all the rows of the table 'categories' as checkboxes inputs, with the product's categories checked, the rest is unchecked.

My code

```php
// edit-product.php

$product_id = $_GET['id'];

       $query = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT
    products.id,
    marque,
    modele,
    categories.category_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(categories.title separator ',') as category_name
FROM
    products
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    product_category on products.id = product_category.product_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    categories on product_category.category_id = categories.category_id
WHERE
    id = :id");

    $query->execute(['id' => $product_id]);
    $product = $query->fetch();

<?php $data_array = explode(',', $product['category_name']); ?>

<?php foreach ($data_array as $key) : ?>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="<?= $key ?>" checked>
<?= $key ?>
    </label><br>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

What I get:

```
// edit-product.php?id=1
//view
# automne  //checked input
# top    //checked input
```

What I want:

```
# automne  //checked input
o hiver       //unchecked 
o printemps   //unchecked
o été         //unchecked
# top    //checked input
```

I tried to make another request with only the categories but it's not working.. please help !

Comment: Does it make sense to GROUP_CONCAT titles but not category_ids ?!?!

Comment: thx for the advice, but it's not the real prob here, if i got the right request im ok..